# File cant be found by bash script after unziping

Tags: bash

I have something like this in my bash script
First all do `rm -rf *` to remove all files from previous unziping
then I copy my war file and unzip it

```
jar xvf file.war
```

in the output for unzipping am having `WEB-INF/classes/myPropFile.properties`

So the file is unzipped.

But when I test if the file is there

```
if [ ! -e pathTo/myPropFile.properties ]
```

File is not there !

When i open console, and check if there is file at specific location, file is there !
What could be the problem, am doing this remotely , and I see no other errors, sometimes I need to refresh path with `cd ..` , `cd pathTo` to be able to see the file, as ls will not refresh it.
Also when I try to open it with less for example, the file is opened, but in console is the strange error that about current directory cant be recovered something ( am recreating directories with this unzipping from previous time )

So this only does not work from script for some reason ?? Is there some way to do refresh paths from script ?

Comment: Just to be clear, you realize `if [ ! -e pathTo/myPropFile.properties ]` passes the test when the path does _not_ exist, rather than if the path exists, right? I think you need to provide more code to give an idea of the expected control flow.

Comment: Yes, am checking if it does not exists.

Comment: Also there is no much more code , delete all, copy war, unzip war, use cat on file

Comment: Yeah, but as noted in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38078267/364696), if these actions are taking place inside a working directory that is being deleted and recreated, your working directory, despite having the same name, is _not_ the same directory, and relative paths from it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the directory that you are currently in (cwd) then bash will complain that you that there is no working directory or it may behave in odd ways (depending on the version of bash).
Basically, don't remove the current working directory.Remove the files from the previous unzip first, then extract from your jar, and finally cd into the directory that was created by the extract.

Comment: Tried that, also removing only files and living folder structure etc, that was just a clue, that I guess can help to find solution, but I understand that this may not be directly connected to my problem